# How to add Cookie in IE 8

Tags: php

In Internet Explorer 8 when I open the browser and I enter username and Password the login becomes successful.  Then without logging out, I close the browser and then I reopen it and find I've been automatically logged out and it requires me to reenter a username and password.

But It works fine in Firefox.

Comment: are u not saving username and password in cookie?? if yes then show the code please..

Answer (score 2):

A few things to check:

- Are you setting the cookie's expiration date? If not, it expires when the browser closes.
- Have you made sure cookies aren't being blocked?
- Are you sure there is no setting to automatically clear cookies?

Things like that. My money's on the first one, though.